# How should I created an SSRS template from a SQL table?

Tags: vba, automation, formatting, expression, ssrs-2012

Only my second stack question, I'm pretty new to ssrs, but I'd rather do it the right way and learn now, then have to come back and fix everything later.

I'm going to create a semi-flexible reporting (SSRS) standard for my company and getting global consensus ahead of time is impossible. My proposed solution will be to create a formatting table that I can update to alter the look and feel of all my reports of one type.  (tables, charts etc.)  I have thought of two ways to do this and I am looking for advice on which is better and if how I am thinking it will work...will actually work.  I am totally willing to research all the specifics of how-to, but I'd really appreciate a hint on how to start.

Is there a way to reference which attribute (e.g. name, background color) your expression is in?  It would be awesome if I could use the same code for all the attribute's expressions and just have that code find it's spot in the table.
something like:

```
attribute.value = lookup(ReportFormataDataset as RFD, attribute.name = 
RFD.name and left(me.name, 3) = RFD.prefix)
```

Alternatively I could run a loop in VBA code to change the attributes based on what's in the table.  I plan to create a report template with naming conventions to help. (e.g. hdr, ttl, bdy prefix)  so it could look like:

```
for each reportItem in report
   for each el in FormatTable
       'make sure the report item is what I think it is, like header
       if left(ReportItem.name, 3) = el.prefix then
           'e.g. backgroundcolor = Blue
           name.value = el.value
       end if
   end loop
end loop
```

but then when would I run it, I would imagine this slowing my report a lot if I did this in the expressions.  Maybe with variables instead?

I found this:
[tips-tricks-ensure-consistency-sql-server-reporting-services-reports](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/tips-tricks-ensure-consistency-sql-server-reporting-services-reports)
but it seems very cumbersome to maintain if I add a formatting requirement later I'll have to add that parameter to all the reports and the attribute.

I know this seems a little fishing-y but I am not sure how either of these would work and I know I could throw days of effort at either when an expert could point me in the right direction in 5 minutes so... sorry if this is not in the 'stack spirit' and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have implemented something similar, and have used the method of setting up a shared dataset that all the reports call.  This returns a single record, that includes all the images, background colours and date formats we might use across the reports (including company logo and branding colours).

If we had a date in a cell for example, we would then set the number format to

```
=First(Fields!FullDateFormat.Value, "ReportConstants")
```

Where `ReportConstants` is the named of the shared dataset.

This also allows us to have the same report deployed both in the UK and the US, yet both use their native date format, as this is set by the database instance, instead of within the report.

Now whether this is the right approach to take or not is another question, but it works for us, using the ~50 reports in multiple locations, without having to configure each one individually all the time.

Is this helpful?

Comment: Thanks Jonnus, that sounds like it should work.  I am also gathering that each attribute has its own column as opposed to a column named 'attribute names' and data of FullDateFormat.
Do you have a style ID and then the data set is populated with the one record matching the ID for that report?

Comment: @Zero Shadow, Yes each attribute has it's own column.  In the example above there is a single column called FullDateFormat.  All our reports follow the same style, but your proposal of a styleID makes sense.  The report could have this as a parameter, and the shared dataset could then return the single row from the database that matches the styleID.